# Set typehint for custom subclass of List - TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I am trying to specify the elements of a returned `List` subclass via [typehinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

```
from typing import Union, List, Tuple, Optional, NewType
from jira import JIRA
from jira.client import ResultList
from jira.resources import Issue

def search(...) -> ResultList[Issue]: # using 'List[Issue]:' or 'ResultList:' as return type hint work
    ...
```

However, I am running in this error:

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

I've tried my luck with [NewType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype), but cannot get it to run as expected. When not specifying the subclass `ResultList[Issue]` and using `List[Issue]` instead, it works. Also, when not mentioning the element type by simply using `ResultList`, it works.

Additional information:

[ResultList Code](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/5c27f6ddafffc6110be1db4749fa67025852bcb6/jira/client.py#L131)

[Issue Code](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/5c27f6ddafffc6110be1db4749fa67025852bcb6/jira/resources.py#L482)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should look at these:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic
- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html
- https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stubs.html

explanation:
**list** and **typing.List** are totally different things
in order to utilize generic you must inherit from **typing.Generic**
if you use third party libs code and cant make changes to **ResultList**, then stubs is a solution
basically you need to define stub for **ResultList** class in *.pyi file like this:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Iterable

T = TypeVar('T')

class ResultList(list, Generic[T]):
    def __init__(
        self, iterable: Iterable[T] = ..., _startAt: int = ..., _maxResults: int = ..., _total: int = ..., _isLast: bool = ...
    ) -> None:
        ...
    ...
```

after that you can use as typing as follows:

```
from unittest import TestSuite

from res import ResultList


class SomeClass:
    pass


def foo() -> 'ResultList[int]':
    return ResultList(iterable=[SomeClass()])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a: 'ResultList[str]' = foo()
# pycharm will highlight "unexpected type error"
```

dont forget to connect stubs in pycharm as it showed in link

Comment: Thanks mate. I have one follow up question. There already exists Docstring documentation in the third party lib. If I add my .pyi stub for `class ResultList`, it seems the existing Docstrings are ignored. Is it possible to mix & match? Can I only add the stub for `class Resultlist` and keep the benefit of the already existing Docstrings? Or do I have to stub everything from the third party lib (at least in client.py)?

Comment: @ChrisGraf
honestly, idk how to resolve issue with docstrings in stubs.  
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000596824-Missing-docstrings-when-pyi-stub-present   
this is the only info about the issue in pycharm that i've found.   
you can stub only needed classes from third-party module.   
you still can see original docstring in class definition (ctrl+b), though its not so convenient as quick doc (ctrl+q)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've used it to implement the typehints into the jira module itself (the source of the OP's original question), should be available from `3.1.0rc1` onwards, the typehints pull request can be found here: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/pull/1023.